# How to access GlobalTempView in SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm learning Databricks and got stuck on the simplest step.

I'd like to utilize my DataFrame from DB's SQL ecosystem

Here are my steps:

```
df = spark.read.csv('dbfs:/databricks-datasets/COVID/covid-19-data/us.csv', header=True, inferSchema=True)
display(df)
```

Everything is fine, df is displayed. Then submitting:

```
df.createOrReplaceGlobalTempView("covid")
```

Finally:

```
%sql

show tables
```

No results are displayed. When trying:

```
display(spark.sql('SELECT * FROM covid LIMIT 10'))
```

Getting the error:

```
[TABLE_OR_VIEW_NOT_FOUND] The table or view `covid` cannot be found
```

When executing:

```
df.createGlobalTempView("covid")
```

Again, I'm getting a message covid already exists.
How to access my df from sql ecosystem, please?

Answer (score 1):

In a Databricks notebook, if you're looking to utilize SQL to query your dataframe loaded in python,
you can do so in the following way (using your example data):

Setup df in python

```
df = spark.read.csv('dbfs:/databricks-datasets/COVID/covid-19-data/us.csv', header=True, inferSchema=True)
```

setup your global view

```
df.createGlobalTempView("covid")
```

Then a simply query in SQL will be equivalent to display() function

```
%sql
SELECT * FROM global_temp.covid
```

If you want to avoid using `global_temp` prefix, use `df.createTempView`